# Haskell/Persistent: Reusing "selectList"

Tags: haskell, yesod, servant

I am trying to write an API in Servant and I am writing a lot of handlers that look like this:

```
getTableA :: Handler [ARecord]
getTableA = do
    xs <- runDB (selectList [] [])
    let records = map (\(Entity _ v) -> v) xs
    return records

getTableB :: Handler [BRecord]
getTableB = do
    xs <- runDB (selectList [] [])
    let records = map (\(Entity _ v) -> v) xs
    return records

getTableC :: Handler [CRecord]
getTableC = do
    xs <- runDB (selectList [] [])
    let records = map (\(Entity _ v) -> v) xs
    return records
```

And so on.

I want to be able to have something more like

```
getTable :: Handler [a]
getTable = do
    xs <- runDB (selectList [] [])
    let records = map (\(Entity _ v) -> v) xs
    return records
```

However I get the error

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘SqlBackend’
            with actual type ‘PersistEntityBackend val’
Relevant bindings include
  getAll :: Handler [val] (bound at src/Novation/Handler.hs:101:1)
In the first argument of ‘runDB’, namely ‘(selectList [] [])’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: xs <- runDB (selectList [] [])
In the expression:
  do { xs <- runDB (selectList [] []);
       let records = map (\ (Entity _ v) -> ...) xs;
       return records }
```

I am hoping that in the end I'll be able to have something like this

```
server :: Server MyAPI
server = getTable :<|> getTable :<|> getTable

type MyAPI = 
         "tableA" :> Get '[JSON] [ARecord]
    :<|> "tableB" :> Get '[JSON] [BRecord]
    :<|> "tableC" :> Get '[JSON] [CRecord]
```

Instead of

```
server :: Server MyAPI
server = getTableA :<|> getTableB :<|> getTableC
```

Comment: I'm afraid we need a more minimal testcase. Could you post an example that doesn't use `Handler` or `runDB`? Those seem like functions that you wrote. (Psychically, though, I am guessing that you're missing constraints on `getTable`. If you look at `selectList`, you'll see that the return values are constrained not only by `MonadIO` but the rather complicated `PersistEntity val, PersistQuery backend, PersistEntityBackend val ~ backend` – although if you're just doing SQL you can abbreviate the last two to just `ToBackendKey SqlBackend val`.)